# How to install all dependencies of angular custom libraries

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, angular-library, npm-build

We have an angular 11 project with more than 20 custom angular libraries created by us.
When we need to run `npm install` we need to change directory to each library. Is there any way we can run `npm install` for all libraries without manually changing directory. Currently we are using a shell script to do the task.

[image]

I want to run `npm install`  inside each of these projects. Ex: dev-about-page, dev-accept-invitation-page ... etc

Comment: you would probably want to migrate to a monorepo structure: https://nx.dev/

Comment: you can setup a custom npm registry, and publish the packages to that registry. Especially when the libraries are used on multiple projects. See for example [this article](https://medium.com/engenharia-noalvo/ways-to-have-your-private-npm-registry-and-a-final-diy-solution-eed001a88e74)

Comment: @JSONDerulo I'm already using custom npm registry and using these libraries in other project. I just want to install libraries dependencies at once.

Comment: I would also suggest to consider a monorepo approach, as @31piy already mentioned. An alternative to NX with less boilerplate is [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces)